# Output error from archive: tar.xz: File format not recognized

Tags: command-line, tor, extension

I have read all the methods at "how to extract an archive with extension .xz", and none of them can extract an archive via terminal. (e.g tor)

The only way to extract an .xz extension is via GUI.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a question.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a question.  YOu don't ask a question.  Just use `xz`/`unxz`

Comment: You're up to 6 edits over 30 minutes - please stop making minor revisions and bumping your post to the top.  Rather, analyze your question, and make all the edits you want to make in one go.  (Bumping posts unnecessarily is bad)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tor has its own documentation right on the website: https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#linux

Here's what the Tor site says to do:

> Download the architecture-appropriate file above, save it somewhere,
>   then run one of the following two commands to extract the package
>   archive:
>
> ```
> tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux32-5.5.5_LANG.tar.xz
> ```
>
> or (for the 64-bit version):
>
> ```
> tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux64-5.5.5_LANG.tar.xz
> ```
>
> (where LANG is the language listed in the filename).
>
> Once that's done, switch to the Tor browser directory by running:
>
> ```
> cd tor-browser_LANG
> ```
>
> (where LANG is the language listed in the filename).
>
> To run Tor Browser, click either on the Tor Browser or the Tor Browser
>   Setup icon or execute the start-tor-browser.desktop file in a
>   terminal:
>
> ```
> ./start-tor-browser.desktop
> ```
>
> This will launch Tor Launcher and once that connects to Tor, it will
>   launch Firefox. Do not unpack or run TBB as root.

In the future, when you ask questions, please include what you're trying to do, instead of posting what seems like a short rant. A little research beforehand wouldn't hurt either, but we can't force you to do that if you don't want to **;-)**

Comment: Output errors: xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a corrupt file?

Comment: I am sure. The only thing i did, was that changed the name of archive from tor-browser-linux64-5.5.5_LANG to tor.

Comment: Are you copying and pasting the command or manually typing it?

Comment: I copying and pasting the command.

Comment: You still could have a corrupt file if the download didn't complete correctly. Try downloading again.

Answer (score 4):

Really ? I tend to just use `xz` - this is the top of the `man` page:

```
XZ(1)                                                              XZ Utils                                                             XZ(1)

NAME
       xz, unxz, xzcat, lzma, unlzma, lzcat - Compress or decompress .xz and .lzma files

SYNOPSIS
       xz [option]...  [file]...

       unxz is equivalent to xz --decompress.
       xzcat is equivalent to xz --decompress --stdout.
       lzma is equivalent to xz --format=lzma.
       unlzma is equivalent to xz --format=lzma --decompress.
       lzcat is equivalent to xz --format=lzma --decompress --stdout.

       When  writing  scripts that need to decompress files, it is recommended to always use the name xz with appropriate arguments (xz -d or
       xz -dc) instead of the names unxz and xzcat.
```

So `xz -d foo.xz` does exactly what you need.

Comment: Output: xz: tor.tar.xz: File format not recognized

Comment: @Morpheus it's generally helpful to include what you're trying to do when you ask a question. It's also helpful to actually ask a question. ;)